# calling include function in echo statement

Tags: php, include

I am using whole code in php so i am using echo statement for displaying divs in html but how could i call php include function in echo statement to call a page see the code below:-

```
 echo "<div style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color: white;'>
 include('botfunction.php');
 </div>";
```

it is not  calling that botfunction.php it just shows the text only as `"include('botfunction.php');"` inside the div tag .

- Please tell me how can i call this php function without separating php and html code  because the whole code is written in php which is impossible to separate.

### Thanks

Comment: why not just put the div wrapper inside the botfuction.php file? then just include the botfunction.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be an absolute nightmare to maintain and if it is impossible to separate then I suggest rewriting from scratch. But as for your question, try this:

```
echo "<div style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color: white;'>";
include('botfunction.php');
echo "</div>";
```

You just need to move the include out of the echo string otherwise it will be evaluated as a string instead of a function

Answer (score 2):

Remove the include from inside the echo.

```
echo "<div style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color: white;'>";
include('botfunction.php');
echo "</div>";
```

which is why it's appearing as text instead of executing the include function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<div style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color: white;'>";
 include('botfunction.php');
 echo "</div>";
```